# Flutter Slidable widget error with onWillDismiss

Tags: flutter, dart

i have slidable widget that returned from ListView, on dismiss item need to be deleted from DB, but user must see alert dialog when he try to dismiss item , so i tried to use onWillDismiss, but flutter gave me error because onWillDismiss: (i don't know what to pass there)

this is code that probably onWillDismiss will return

```
return showDialog<bool>(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Delete'),
                content: Text('Item will be deleted'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Cancel'),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Ok'),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The showDialog function should be passed to `confirmDismiss` and not `onDismissed`.

```
Dismissible(
  onDismissed: (_) => {}, // Here pass your method to delete the item from database
  confirmDismiss: (_) => _showMyDialog(),
  key: UniqueKey(),
  child: Card(
    elevation: 1,
    child: ListTile(),
  ),
)
```

`onDismissed` will call the method to delete item from database.

Your code seems to be ok. Here is the `_showMyDialog()` function passed to `confirmDismiss` in my exemple :

```
Future<bool?> _showMyDialog() async {
  return showDialog<bool>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Delete'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: const <Widget>[
              Text('Item will be deleted'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Cancel'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Confirm'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```